# Fill out pdf fields with Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf

I've looking to fill out a pdf with a form data, but can only find librarys to make new pdfs or my html layouts into a pdf.  I'm looking to simply fill out fields of a pdf.

I'm wondering two things, when a pdf has fillable fields, how can i read the source to see what those fillable names are, and secondly is there a library to do this?  I've already looked into node-jspdf, but it doesn't do what I am looking for.

Comment: What languages are you comfortable with and can you run Java on your server?

Comment: Java, javascript, php.  and I not right now, and no java on the server

Answer (score 0):

I found this for node.  https://github.com/tpisto/pdf-fill-form

I am currently using it and I can pull the fields from a pdf and there is methods to write to those fields and then create a pdf from it..

hoping it works out..